# Login Test with Codeception and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, codeception

I'm learning Codeception using Laravel 4, and I was wondering, how do you manage to write a functional test to test a feature that requires you to be logged in order to see the page?

For example, if I test that I have to be  on /posts and see "My Posts", then this would not work, because I'm not logged in, and I'll get "Log In" instead. Do I have to write the code to first test that I'm logged in for every test that requires to be logged in?

Comment: You can create a helper that logs you in.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your login step in helper class in _support folder. 
However, I recommend use Step Objects http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#StepObjects  for multiple user roles.